# Criar diretórios e arquivos em IOS utilizando IONIC framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ios, ionic, app

Preciso executar uma especie de CRUD em diretórios e arquivos através de um aplicativo IOS.

Este aplicativo utiliza como base o IONIC framework, que por sua vez, utiliza recursos do Cordova e AngularJS.

As dúvidas são:

- Em relação as permissões, o sistema IOS permite esse tipo de funcionalidade?
- Se sim, através do que exatamente é possível criar esses arquivos e diretórios? (AngularJS, Javascript "puro", Cordova, ou até mesmo libs como Jquery, etc).
- Como é possível criar, ler, modificar e deletar esses arquivos e diretórios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível utilizando o método window.requestFileSystem, que é nativo do Cordova. Não se esqueça de adicionar a permissão para leitura/escrita de arquivos no seu arquivo de configuração. No caso do iOs, edite o seu arquivo config.xml adicionando essas linhas:

```
<feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

E abaixo segue um exemplo de como usar o requestFileSystem, para abrir a pasta foor e criar o arquivo bar.txt

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
   fileSystem.root.getDirectory("foo", {create: true}, gotDir);
}

function gotDir(dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile("bar.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true}, gotFile);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {
    // manipule o arquivo aqui da forma que você quiser
}
```

Comment: +1, vou testar a implementação e logo após retorno para marcar a resposta como correta. De momento, obrigado!

Comment: Ziron, fiz uma segunda pergunta relacionada a essas necessidade, porém agora voltado ao armazenamento em nuvem. Se achar interessante, esse é o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123842/sincronizar-arquivos-gerados-por-cordova-em-app-ios-com-servidores-em-nuvem