# Sincronizar arquivos gerados por Cordova em app IOS com servidores em nuvem

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, api, ionic, app

Conforme [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123805/criar-diret%C3%B3rios-e-arquivos-em-ios-utilizando-ionic-framework),

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e parte da funcionalidade do mesmo é executar uma especie de CRUD em diretórios e arquivos através de um aplicativo IOS, que baseado na resposta da pergunta anterior será feito através do cordova usando [requestFileSystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

O aplicativo utiliza como base o IONIC framework, que por sua vez, utiliza recursos do Cordova e AngularJS.

A dúvida agora é a respeito da possibilidade de sincronizar esse "CRUD" em nuvem como uma forma de backup. Por exemplo com uma API.

Então gostaria de saber:

Posso utilizar um servidor como o Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox, ou outros, para essa funcionalidade?

Se sim, como posso fazer-lo?

Leve em consideração que os arquivos serão primeiramente criados pelo aplicativo através do *requestFileSystem* e posteriormente armazenados em um desses servidores ou podendo apenas ser criados e manipulados diretamente no servidor desconsiderando o *requestFileSystem*.

Comment: Você está usando algum servidor ou seu app funciona sozinho?

Comment: Ele funciona de maneira independente, sem servidor.

Comment: Bem, eu aconselho a usar um servidor, uma vez que para subir os arquivos você vai ter que fornecer credenciais. Ficaria inseguro deixar o upload de forma direta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer utilizando a api do dropbox mesmo. Te aconselho a criar uma api própria, porque você irá precisar fornecer dados confidenciais para acessar o dropbox, e fica inseguro fazer isso pelo cliente, uma vez que os dados podem ser facilmente interceptados. Escolha a linguagem que mais lhe convir parar criar a api de backup e então utilize o dropbox, ele tem bibliotecas prontas para isso em diversas linguagens, e a implementação é bem simples.

Vide: https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: +1, mas considerando o fato de que apenas eu terei acesso há esses dados no dropbox e estou procurando uma alternativa para reduzir custos, se eu utilizar o OAuth 2.0, ainda assim esse processo feito em client-side se torna inseguro?

Comment: Sim, alguém poderia interceptar as requisições que o aplicativo está fazendo, pegar suas credenciais da api e ter acesso aos dados de todos seus usuários no dropbox